# How can I remove Applications from Security & Privacy?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, security, mojave

Is it possible to completely remove apps from the various privacy categories in System Preferences?

System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy

[image]

Comment: Do you mean specifically for calendars?

Comment: Calendars, Contacts, Photos... Generally speaking, how do we remove them entirely?

Comment: Unchecking them should do the trick no?

Answer (score 29):

To remove *all* apps from a particular Privacy category, open Terminal.app and type the following command, then type the Return key:

```
tccutil reset CATEGORY
```

where CATEGORY is one of:

- Accessibility
- AddressBook
- AppleEvents (i.e. Automation)
- Calendar
- Camera
- Microphone
- Photos
- Reminders
- ScreenCapture (for the Screen Recording list)
- SystemPolicyAllFiles (for the Full Disk Access list)
- SystemPolicyDesktopFolder
- SystemPolicyDeveloperFiles
- SystemPolicyDocumentsFolder
- SystemPolicyDownloadsFolder
- SystemPolicyNetworkVolumes
- SystemPolicyRemovableVolumes
- SystemPolicySysAdminFiles

If you want to remove only a particular app, you need to first [determine its Bundle ID](https://superuser.com/q/346369/41872). Once you know that, issue the command:

```
tccutil reset CATEGORY BUNDLEID
```

**Note: Specifying an app's Bundle ID appears to require macOS Mojave (10.14) or later.**

You could also remove all apps from *all* categories:

```
tccutil reset All
```

Though this might freeze your Mac on macOS 10.15 and later, see comment below.

---

In the example given in the question, the following commands would remove Terminal and Chrome from Calendars.

First, determine their Bundle IDs:

```
osascript -e 'id of app "Terminal"'
```

shows `com.apple.Terminal`. Same for "Chrome" gives: `com.google.Chrome`. Now we can reset them:

```
tccutil reset Calendars com.apple.Terminal
tccutil reset Calendars com.google.Chrome
```

Pro tip:

This is a one-liner doing the same:

```
tccutil reset Calendars `osascript -e 'id of app "Chrome"'`
```

More info in this blog article: [Managing Mojave’s privacy protection: Privacy controls](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/09/17/managing-mojaves-privacy-protection-privacy-controls/).

Comment: On Catalina, `tccutil reset All` resulted in terminal not accepting input, my keyboard not working anymore and my mouse unable to click. I had to hard-reboot with the power key.

Comment: The category is missing ScreenCapture for screen recording.

Comment: @RonnieLiew If you see ways to improve a post, please use the edit functionality to do so.

Comment: Is there a way to find out bundle identifier of a deleted app (other than reinstalling it)?

Comment: @zyy It might still be found in the Launch Services Database. You can dump that with the cmd `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump`

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann Thanks so much! I think using `lsregister` I was able to find the ID (`com.eusoft.freeeudic`) used by the app, but the `tccutil` still tells me `No such bundle identifier`. Anyway I guess I should let go of it!

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! I ran `lsappinfo` (with no arguments) (https://superuser.com/a/1004714/74576) and found my bundleID.  Then `tccutil reset Accessibility emojipicker` did the job.

Answer (score 3):

I tried clicking on the application you want to remove, but not the checkbox and then clicking the remove button (-). It worked for me, but I'm not sure if it will work for others as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the checkbox prevents the application from using those services.

You cannot remove the listings directly from this window as they have requested these permissions in the past. For non-system apps like Chrome, you can remove the application from your machine and it will remove the listing from the privacy pane.